# How to delete an API resource in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I ran:

```
kubectl api-resources | grep "External"
externalmetrics                                     metrics.aws                    true         ExternalMetric
```

I want to delete this `metrics.aws` API resource, but I am not even sure how it was deployed. How can I delete this safely?

Comment: Can you paste the complete output of `kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1"` to your question?

Comment: Its giving an error
`kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1"
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- If it is a not a standard resource, then It might be implemented as a "Customer Resource Definition (crds)"

```bash
kubectl get crds | grep externalmetrics
```

- Check if there are any Custom Resources created under this crd and delete them if there any :

```bash
kubectl get externalmetrics
kubectl delete externalmetrics --all
```

- Then delete that CRD

```bash
kubectl delete crd externalmetrics
```

- Check if it is gone from api-resources list

```bash
kubectl get api-resources
```

**Update:**

If you see `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "v1beta1"` error then run the following command to remove it:

```bash
kubectl delete apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
```

Comment: The `kubectl delete apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io` thing was what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; I wanted to completely remove **PodSecurityPolicy**, which was added when installing a kube-prometheus chart.

```
podsecuritypolicies psp policy/v1beta1 false PodSecurityPolicy
```

This worked for me:

`kubectl get apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io` -> this returns the list.

`kubectl delete apiservice v1beta1.policy` -> this deletes it.